# How to use Visual C++ 2005 Express and Visual Studio Express 2013 on the same computer?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-2005

I would like to use both Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition and Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop on the same computer. What's a good way to accomplish this?

I imagine that installing Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition on a computer that already has Visual Studio Express 2013 installed would cause unexpected errors and break the current installation, or the installation would fail automatically because there already is a newer version installed.

The reason why I want both is because there is a lot of learning material written for both the 2005 and the 2013 editions. There are more programming books written for the 2005 edition actually.

I essentially want to know how I can isolate the two and still use them both in parallel without any problems caused by conflicting files, registry keys, environment settings, etc.

Comment: Up until recently I had multiple versions of Visual Studio installed side-by-side and they didn't conflict. You could set up a virtual machine to hold one of the installations if you want absolute certainty, though.

Comment: By default, they install into different folders. And for a very long time, it has been possible to install and run multiple versions.

Comment: And hey, you also could have [searched: multiple versions of visual studio on one computer](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple+versions+of+visual+studio+on+one+computer&oq=multiple+versions+of+visu&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.6502j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=multiple+versions+of+visual+studio+on+one+computer)

Comment: You just installed to different directories? I have thought about using one VM for one edition and another VM for the other. But doesn't that affect the compile and run-time efficiency? It's not as native as having the IDE installed and running directly in Windows?

Comment: Unless you tell it differently, it will install to different directories. So just let it do that (or at least make the directories you select *different*).

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to bring in a virtual machine for this? You are making it way too complicated. Install to default folders or make sure the folder you specify includes what version it is. Then you have two (or more) versions installed. Two icons on the desktop. Two development environments to run.

Comment: ["We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2012 before you install Visual Studio 2013."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) I have already installed 2013 edition. Can I still install 2005 edition on top of that?

Comment: @crashmstr I'm not trying to bring in a VM, I just said it could be used if op wants absolute certainty of no conflict. I also mentioned I hadn't had any issues in my experience with side-by-side VS installs...

Comment: @sammyg *recommend* vs. *must*. Yes, you can. It generally works *best* if you do them in release order, but you *can* install them later. You probably want to make sure you check for updates after, and if you have issues with the newer once, do a repair on the newer version.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question. I just want the 2005 and the latest 2013 edition. I'm a total noob when it comes to programming, and I haven't worked with an IDE before. I don't want to experiment with it too much, I just want a working setup on my computer. I wanted to play it safe and ask before I install. I could have tried installing it anyway. But according to the MS article above I will have to uninstall 2013, install 2005, then reinstall 2013 edition. Is that necessary?...

Comment: @crashmstr I guess I will just have to try that and see what happens. I will install 2005 on top of 2013. Thanks!

Comment: Nine years is a *long* time in software engineering.  VS2005 is not appropriate anymore, both operating systems and the C++ language have changed far too much.  You should also have a major problem getting that Express edition registered and obtaining the required service packs.  Don't waste your time on outdated tools and books.